# Windows 8 Desktop Won't Auto Refresh

Tags: windows-8, desktop

Recently, my desktop won't show any new files unless I press F5. This is a bit annoying, and none of the fixes on the Microsoft website help. What do I do?

Comment: it does this even after a restart?